# How to start ordered list from number other then 1 in Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I have Markdown file that look like this:

```
1. First

Some text and other stuff

2. Second

Othe stuff
```

But after render it's generated as:

```
1. First

Some text and other stuff

1. Second

Othe stuff
```

Is there a solution to make second ordered list start from 2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jekyll is using Kramdown as Markdown parser that support setting custom attributes (see [docs](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#inline-attribute-lists)). And html5 support start attribute that change start number of ordered list see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-start).

The markdown file need to look like this:

```
1. First

Some text and other stuff

{:start="2"}
2. Second

Othe stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way in this case is to simply indent the `Some text and other stuff` paragraph with 4 spaces. Then `2. Second` will know to continue the numbering.

Comment: Indentation not always work, for instance if you want to put a code block below the item.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following syntax:

```
1\.

2\.

3\.
```

Comment: This will create text, not a list. The question is about the ordered list.